# Different float input and output

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-accuracy

```
float amount;
printf("Enter the amount:\n");
scanf("%f", &amount);
// input: 100.10
printf("%f", amount);
```

Output: 100.099998

The problem is that the output is not 100.10 same as the input;

Comment: please search SO: similar questions asked thousands of times. Search for float precision representation

Comment: Floating-point numbers are always stored as the nearest approximation possible and not exact numbers. Read this [**article**](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/Comparing%20floating%20point%20numbers.htm) for a good understanding on storing and comparing floating-point numbers.

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 2):

Floating point numbers like `100.10` has no exact binary representations. That's why you encountered rounding error.

Note that there is something more behind, `%f` in `printf` actually expects a `double` argument, so here `amount` is converted to `double` in the `printf` call.

The reason is, variable argument functions like `printf` always promote their variable argument parts, that's why `printf` has no format specifier for `float`, because it always sees `double`. So a better program to demonstrate your question is to use `double` instead:

```
double amount;
printf("Enter the amount:\n");
scanf("%lf", &amount);
printf("%f", amount);
```

You'll still get rounding error, but no conversion from `float` to `double` is done. And to demonstrate the program, you may need to print more digits as `double` is more accurate.